# How does this red liquid crystal display (LCD) work?

Tags: liquid-crystal

This Casio G-3110 has a passive display showing red when two black layers of what appears to be ordinary LCD overlap. How does this work? When tilted as in this photo the black layers do not fully overlap and the effects can be seen.

[image]